# Categorically vs Undeniably

Tags: meaning

I was going through one of my CAE tests when I came across the following example:

> "It was not until 1939 that the two ladies who took the photos
>   admitted these were fake. They simply cut out pictures of fairies from
>   a book and arranged them among flowers. The results are **undeniably**
>   beautiful."

However, one of the options for the bolded word was **categorically**.

Do they not mean the same thing? Why is categorically incorrect?

The suggestion I found in this link introduced me to the same definition, I feel. http://www.dictionary.com/browse/categorically?s=t

Comment: Beauty being in the eye of the beholder (subjective), it is not an absolute. 'Undeniably' has the looser sense 'Maybe one in a billion would deny this'.

Answer (score 1):

**categorically** bears very specific connotation of denying smth / categorically reject smth / categorically deny the charges/the guilt / It is categorically false. / categorically dispute smth.

It doesn't usually collocate with **beautiful**, though I clearly remember a moment from one TV-show when a man compliments a woman saying "[You look] **Categorically stunning**!" But I guess some literary device, which I don't know the name of, is used here.